# Saving images to array in NSUserDefaults+showing in table=done, how do i delete a image in a specific cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here is the current code.

https://github.com/charmaex/photo-table

So it is a table view and on the top right there is a add image button, after you add image it saves locally and shows the image on the table view. If you add another it saves as well. Close the app and open and it loads the images that were saved locally. How can i delete an image from a specific cell? For example there are 5 images in the table, how do i delete the third one that was saved (not just remove it from the table).

Comment: I hope you are just saving filenames to NSUserDefaults, not actual images (You'd have to covert the images to NSData in order to be able to save them to user defaults anyway.) Post your current code.

Comment: look in the github. thats what I'm doing. everything is working fine saving and loading the images, i just want to know how to delete an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to remove the imageName from array and save it back to the NSUserDefault as you said you are saving in NSUserDefaults. Also write to logic to delete the file from documents directory.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool      
{     return true 
} 

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{ 
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) 
    { 
         imageArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row) 
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(imageArray, forKey: "imageList")
         NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
         tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
     } 
}
```